# how to draw on top of the camera full screen view in an ios app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, html

I would like to place a compass, or an image on top of the camera view in my iOS app?

Background:
   I am creating an app, that would open the camera in the native side with is the iOS, then in the HTML side without using phone gap, or cordova. I am using Native bridging, i would like to place a moving compass on top of the camera view on my iOS app, what methods should i use? any helpful code?

thank you

Comment: Check with imagePickerController's cameraOverlayView property. You can set any view as cameraOverlayView.

Comment: how can i put a compass on there that is movable when the iphone moves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `cameraOverlayView` property of `UIImagePickerController` to set an overlay on top of camera. Check [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) for more details. You can add any `UIView` as the overlayview.

In order to use the magnetometer, you'll have to use CoreLocation and the following delegate method:

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
             didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
```

to rotate a `UIView` to point North:

```
float heading = newHeading.magneticHeading; //in degrees
float headingDegrees = (heading*M_PI/180); //assuming needle points to top of iphone. convert to radians
self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(headingDegrees);
```

You might also find these questions useful:

- [Use native iOS compass within an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264838/use-native-ios-compass-within-an-app)
- [How can i draw a compass like iphone 3gs in ios4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390843/how-can-i-draw-a-compass-like-iphone-3gs-in-ios4)